# Selecting if no delimiter, and no selecting if it is

Tags: regex, string

I have string like `"smth 2sg. smth"`, and sometimes `"smth 2sg.| smth."`.

What mask should I use for selecting `"2sg."` if string  does not contains`"|"`, and select nothing if string does contains `"|"`?

Comment: Will it always be exactly "2sg."?

Comment: @HappyCoder number can changes, but letters always is "sg". Also, it always have dot.

Comment: Any particular programming environment are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 methods. They both use something called a Negative Lookahead, which is used like so:

```
(?!data)
```

When this is inserted into a RegEx, it means if `data` exists, the RegEx will not match.

More info on the Negative Lookahead can be found [**here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

### Method 1 (shorter)

Just capture `2sg.`

Try this RegEx:

```
(\dsg\.)(?!\|)
```

Use `(\d+...` if the number could be longer than 1 digit

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3me)</kbd>

How it works:

```
(        # To capture (2sg.)
    \d       # Digit (2)
    sg       # (sg)
    \.       # . (Dot)
)
(?!\|)   # Do not match if contains |
```

---

### Method 2 (longer but safer)

Match the whole string and capture `2sg.`

Try this RegEx:

```
^\w+\s*(\dsg\.)(?!\|)\s*\w+\.?$
```

Use `(\d+sg...` if the number could be longer than 1 digit

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3m8)</kbd>

How it works:

```
^        # String starts with ...
\w+\s*   # Letters then Optional Whitespace (smth )
(        # To capture (2sg.)
    \d       # Digit (2)
    sg       # (sg)
    \.       # . (Dot)
)
(?!\|)       # Do not match if contains |
\s*          # Optional Whitespace
\w+          # Letters (smth)
\.?          # Optional . (Dot)
$            # ... Strings ends with
```

Comment: Eugeni, be careful. This will not work for multiple digits.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I updated the answer, thanks. I assumed it would only be one digit long. And who is **Eugeni**?

Comment: @Druzon, the author of this post. He has his name in cyrillic which reads as, Evgenii.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
(\d*sg\.)(?!\|)
```

It assumes that there is(or there is no)number followed by `sg.` and not followed by `|`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(\dsg\.)[^\|]*$
```

Explanation:

```
^  : starts from the beginning of the string
.* : accepts any number of initial characters (even nothing)
(\dsg\.) : looks for the group of digit + "sg." 
[^\|]*  : considers any number of following characters except for | 
$ : stops at the end of the string
```

You can now select your string by getting the first group from your regex

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(\d+sg.(?!\|))
```

depending on your programming environment, it can be little bit different but will get your result.

For more information see [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)